# The Equivalent to LINQ's `FirstOrDefault` (predicate) in Rails's Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Entity Framework, you can use a predicate method to get the first column in query based on a conditional, i.e. `FirstOrDefault((row) => row.Something == "bla" && row.Good == true)`

How do you do that in Ruby on Rails?
Without the usage of the `where` method?

Answer (score 1):

`Model.find_by`

You can pretty much pass the same type of query arguments as in the `where` method

Examples:

```
User.find_by("name like 'bob' and locked is 0")
# Or
User.find_by(name: 'bob', locked: false)
```

If not found, returns `nil` much like with `FirstOrDefault`